# Como quitar campos del pdf creado con gravity forms

Tags: wordpress, pdf, wordpress-plugin

Hola estoy usando por primera vez un plugin para wordpress llamado gravity forms, por ahora lo estoy encontrando muy útil. Este plugin sirve para crear formularios de una forma rápida e intuitiva, pero también tiene diversos add-ons o añadidos al plugin muy interesantes como por ejemplo el que una vez enviado el formulario crea el pdf con todo el formulario.

Hasta aquí todo bien, la cuestión es que al crear el pdf no quiero incluir todos los campos del formulario, quiero quitar varios pero he buscado y no encuentro la forma alguien sabe si esto se puede realizar y como hacerlo? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final buscando he encontrado solución, dejo la respuesta por si alguien pueda necesitarlo.

Simplemente habría que ir a edición del propio formulario, al campo que se quiera quitar del pdf, ir a su pestaña de "apariencia" y en clase css personalizada poner la palabra "exclude", con esto al construir el pdf no se incluirán todas aquellos campos que tengan dicha clase.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación, funciona perfectamente. Lo que no entiendo es porque NO funciona para el campo del precio del producto, me tiene loca y no encuentro la solución. ¿Alguien conoce la pocima???